# 'Takeown' command not working

Tags: windows-vista

I'm trying to reduce the size of the 'ManifestCache' folder on a 32-bit Windows Vista Ultimate computer.  I type "Takeown /f c:\windows\winsxs\ManifestCache*" and I get the following error message: "The current logged on user does not have ownership privileges on the file (or folder): "c:\windows\winsxs\ManifestCache\6.0.6002.18005_001c11ba_blobs.bin".  The user is in a workgroup and has administrator privileges.  Also, I shut down the the 'trustedinstaller' prior to attempting to take ownership.  Thanks, in advance, for your help!
- Charles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely are not running this from an elevated command prompt.

Click Start > type `cmd` into the search box > right click on `cmd.exe` and select `Run As Administrator`

Then try the command again.

Comment: @Charles, The best way to notice this is to ensure that the UI for two type of cmd prompts (administrator or not) are different. E.g. If I open an administrator cmd prompt, the background is green as opposed to white background if its opened without cmd prompt.